# django-silk Page not found

Tags: django-silk

I did the install and I see the tables silk makes in my database so I know it is working but when I do the 127.0.0.1:8000/silk I get Page not found.

I did add the path('silk', include('silk.urls', namespace='silk')), to my urls file. I added 'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware', after 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'. Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb! I forgot to add the / after silk. silk/ is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the order of urlpatterns in url.py, I needed add path at the front instead of extending the list later on like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("silk/", include("silk.urls", namespace="silk")),
```